# $_SESSION[''] not working in PHP

Tags: php, session, authentication, location, session-variables

I'm currently using MAMP, however I have also tested with GoDaddy (My Web Host).

Here is the page that receives the information off the HTML form and sets the authuser.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['user'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['pass'];
    $_SESSION['authuser'] = 0;
    //Check to see if login is good
    if (($_SESSION['username'] == 'Admin') and
        ($_SESSION['password'] == 'Password1')) {
    $_SESSION['authuser'] == 1;
        echo  "CORRECT";
        echo $_SESSION['authuser'];
    } else {
        echo "Sorry but you dont have permission to view this page!";
        echo $_SESSION['username'];
        echo $_SESSION['password'];
        echo $_SESSION['authuser'];
        exit();
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Find my Favorite Movie!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
          $myFavorite = urlencode("The Life of Brian");
          echo "<a href= 'moviesite.php?favmovie=$myFavorite'>";
          echo "Click here to see information about my favorite movie!";
          echo "</a>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

This page loads due to the fact that the username and password do match, but when I go onto the next page it says that I don't have permission to view the page because my $_SESSION['authuser'] = 0. (The value is not changing even though I set it to 1 when the Username and password were correct.)
Here is the page that throws me the error incase it makes a difference.

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['authuser'] != 1) {
    echo "Sorry, but you don't have permission to view this page!";
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
    echo $_SESSION['password'];
    echo $_SESSION['authuser'];
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Movie Site - <?php echo $_REQUEST['favmovie']; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo "Welcome to our site ";
            echo $_SESSION['username'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "My Favorite Movie Is ";
            echo $_REQUEST['favmovie'];
            echo "<br>";
            $movierate = 5;
            echo "My movie rating for this movie is: ";
            echo $movierate;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried changing the path for the temp folder multiple different times, and I have also tried putting this at the top of my pages below the

```
ini_set('session.save_path', '/Users/Joseph/Desktop/PHPTEMP/');
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($(_SESSION)` to see what's coming up in both scripts? checked the value of `session_id()` to see if you're dealing with the SAME session in both scripts? Checked the return value of `session_start()` to see if the session even started?

Comment: Try to hardcode  $_SESSION['username'] = 'Admin' and $_SESSION['password'] = 'Password1'; in first file and check it's working or not? if not then your post value are wrong

Comment: `$_SESSION['authuser'] == 1;` *hm...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change:

```
$_SESSION['authuser'] == 1;
```

With

```
$_SESSION['authuser'] = 1;
```

because in this way you do an assignment!